# Show text letter by letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the most elegant way of showing an html text letter by letter (like videogame captions) using CSS and JavaScript?

While I'm sure that his can be solved using a brute-force approach (say, splitting the characters and print them one by one using `jQuery.append()`), I'm hoping there's some CSS3 (pseudo-elements?) or JQuery magic to do this more elegantly.

Extra points if the solution considers inner HTML content.

Comment: Does it need to be individual letters popping in? Or can it be a smooth reveal?

Comment: If the smooth reveal shows the letters sequentially, yes.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="msg"/>
```

Javascript

```
var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {   
  if (index < message.length) {
    $(target).append(message[index++]);
    setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
  }
}
```

Call with:

```
$(function () {
  showText("#msg", "Hello, World!", 0, 500);   
});
```

Comment: @Luke: It really help to add a fiddle!

Comment: Once this is running, how would you stop it from continuing? For example, let's say this is called during a click. As it's running, the user clicks again to display another message before the first call is finished. This causes the two loops to overlap. How do you stop the first loop from continuing?

Comment: I believe the anonymous function inside the setTimeout is unnecessary, as it only contains a function call, which is the purpose of the setTimeout itself. setTimeout can pass the parameters to the function, when you just add them after the delay.

So, this should work - and works, as I tested it:
`setTimeout(showText, interval, target, message, index, interval);`

Answer (score 14):

If a smooth reveal is reasonable then I think this should be pretty straightforward. Untested, but this is how I imagine it would work

**html**

```
<div id="text"><span>The intergalactic space agency</span></div>
```

**css**

```
div#text { width: 0px; height: 2em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;  }
```

**jQuery**

```
var spanWidth = $('#test span').width();
$('#text').animate( { width: spanWidth }, 1000 );
```

Okay, I couldn't resist and made a fiddle. One little code error that I fixed. Looks good to me though!

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/6qQrN/1/

Answer (score 7):

100% vanilla javascript, strict mode, unobtrusive html,

```
function printLetterByLetter(destination, message, speed){
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += message.charAt(i);
        i++;
        if (i > message.length){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, speed);
}

printLetterByLetter("someElement", "Hello world, bonjour le monde.", 100);
```

Answer (score 3):

You really should just `append`, or show/hide.

However, if for some odd reason you don't want to alter your text, you can use this overly-complicated-for-no-good-reason piece of code:

**HTML:**

```
<p>I'm moving slowly...<span class="cover"></span></p>
```

**CSS:**

```css
p {
    font-family: monospace;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.cover {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var $p = $('p'),
    $cover = $('.cover'),
    width = $p.width(),
    decrement = width / $p.text().length;

function addChar()
{        
    $cover.css('width', '-=' + decrement);

    if ( parseInt( $cover.css('width') ) < width )
    {
        setTimeout(addChar, 300);
    }
}

addChar();
```

And finally, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dDGVH/236/

But, seriously, don't use this...

Comment: +1 Interesting idea. Pity it shows all the lines at the same time. Maybe it can be made to work with a few changes.

Comment: @hgpc: It sure could, but that would invlove 2 `.cover` spans. This is getting more and more complicated by the minute. Are you sure you don't want to simply append?

Comment: Most likely I'll use append, but I find your idea interesting anyway. Also, it has the advantage that it preserves inner html content.

Answer (score 3):

Make your code more elegant by preparing promises for each iteration, then execute them as second step where you can inject DOM logic.

```js
const message = 'Solution using Promises';

const typingPromises = (message, timeout) =>
  [...message].map(
    (ch, i) =>
      new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(message.substring(0, i + 1));
        }, timeout * i);
      })
  );

typingPromises(message, 140).forEach(promise => {
  promise.then(portion => {
    document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = portion;
  });
});
```

```html
<div ><p></p></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the React version using hooks.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = ({ speed, msg }) => {
  const Typer = ({ speed = 250, children = " Introduce your text" }) => 
{
  const [idx, setidx] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => setidx((v) => v + 1), speed);
    return () => window.clearInterval(timer);
  });

  return <div>{children.substr(0, idx)}</div>;
};
return (
  <div>
    <Typer speed={speed} children={msg}></Typer>
  </div>
 );
};

export default App;
```

and the main index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const message2 = "This is some text to get typed on time";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App speed={100} msg={message2} />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Have a look at [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-leftpad-91xm6?file=/src/App.js:0-74)

Answer (score 2):

I made a tiny jquery plugin for that. First you need to make sure that the text will be visible if javascript is disabled, and if not, redisplay the text letter by letter.

```
$.fn.retype = function(delay) {
    var el = this,
        t = el.text(),
        c = t.split(''),
        l = c.length,
        i = 0;
    delay = delay || 100;
    el.empty();
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(i < l) el.text(el.text() + c[i++]); 
        else clearInterval(interval);
    }, delay);
};
```

Usage will be just as easy as this:

```
$('h1').retype();
```

Comment: Wow! This crashed my browser after applying it to a collection of more than one element ... but works great otherwise.

Do you have it on github? I'd like to contribute a few things.

Comment: No, I don't have it on github, but feel free to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

When I did this I ran into the problem of a word jumping from the end of one line to the begging of the next as it the letters appeared to get around this I used to side by side spans, one of which the text was transparent, the other visible and simply moved letters one by one from the invisible span to the visible. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk9uw77s/).

HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <span class='visible'></span><span class='invisible'></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.visible {
  color: black;
} 

.invisible {
  color: transparent;
}
```

JS

```
var text = "Whatever you want your text to be here",
    soFar = "";

var visible = document.querySelector(".visible"),
    invisible = document.querySelector(".invisible");

invisible.innerHTML = text;
var t = setInterval(function(){
  soFar += text.substr(0, 1),
  text = text.substr(1);

  visible.innerHTML = soFar;
  invisible.innerHTML = text;

  if (text.length === 0) clearInterval(t);
}, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla JavaScript version of @armen.shimoon's answer:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    showText("#msg", "Hello, World!", 0, 100);

});

let showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {
    if (index < message.length) {
        document.querySelector(target).innerHTML =
            document.querySelector(target).innerHTML + message[index++];
        setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="msg"></div> 
<span id="text_target"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on armen.shimoon's:

```
var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {    
    if (index <= message.length && $(target).is(':visible')) { 
        $(target).html(message.substr(0, index++)); 
        setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval); 
    } 
}
```

message[index++] wasn't working in my jquery webpage - I had to change it to substr. Also my original text uses HTML and the text that is typed uses HTML formatting (br, b, etc). I've also got the function stopping if the target has been hidden.

Comment: In browsers such as Chrome the < is sometimes visible when you're putting in some HTML code into the target...

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each letter in span tag, because anonymous html elements cannot be styled. Then reveal one span at a time. This avoids some innerText / innerHTML issues (no DOM reflow?) but can be overkill in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Vanillla

```
(function () {

var showText = function(target, msg, index, interval){

  var el = document.getElementById(target);

  if(index < msg.length){
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + msg.charAt(index);
    index = index + 1;
    setTimeout(function(){
      showText(target,msg,index,interval);
    },interval);
  }

};


showText("id", "Hello, World!", 0, 50);   

})();
```

you could improve on this code by changing it so you only get the el one time due to the fact that it takes a bit of resources to modify the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

there is a good answer how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832400/fade-in-letter-by-letter-with-jquery):
this is a way that you can manipulate each letter with any .animate() property available, not with hacks like covering the text with s etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the same problem and I came up with this solution that seems to work.

HTML

```
<div id='target'></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
  var message = 'Hello world';
  var index = 0;

  function displayLetter() {
    if (index < message.length) {
      $('#target').append(message[index++]);
    }
    else{
      clearInterval(repeat);
    }
  }
  var repeat = setInterval(displayLetter, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple libraries for this now. There are [TypeItJs](https://typeitjs.com/) and [TypedJS](https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) both of them allow for html to be in the thing that you are typing out as well as numerous other methods that assist in animating Typewriter effects.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I will type is the answer [Show text letter by letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264974/show-text-letter-by-letter/7265613#7265613) , but I made some changes to it

HTML

```
<h1>
    <span id="msg"></span>
</h1>
```

Javacript

```
var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {    
  if (index < message.length) { 
    //$(target).append(message[index++]);
    $(target).text($(target).text() + message[index++]);
    setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval); 
  } 
}

$(function () { 
  showText("#msg", "Hello, World!", 0, 80);    
  //showText("#msg", "Hello, World!", 0, 500);
});
```

CSS

```
#msg {
    color: #6d67c6;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function textRoll(message, interval){
   setTimeout(() => {
         para.innerHTML += message.charAt(0);
         return textRoll(message.slice(1))
   }, interval)
}
```

Comment: Do you mind offering some explanation of your code?

Comment: yah you just pass in 2 parameters when calling, one with the message to be typed up, the other with how fast you want it to come out. you just plus equal the first charactor of the message to the place it needs to b put(I wanted it in the para.innerhtml in this case but that can b changed). then you recall the function but cut off the first letter so that the first letter now is the next letter in your mressage.

Comment: When someone asks for explanation you can reply in the comments, but if the request is general and would result in the answer being improved by including it is is a good idea to edit the answer to include that explanation. When answering an eight year old question with fifteen existing answers it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.

Comment: Tbh I don't understand what your saying. I just put in this answer bcuz I looked up the question to see if there was a way to do it and then realized that I can do it shorter. So I put up the answer bcuz I thought it was alot simpler than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery

```js
var spanWidth = $('#text span').width();
$('#text').animate( { width: spanWidth }, 3000 );
```

```css
div#text { width: 0px; height: 2em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"><span>Hello World !</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here with CSS only approach, i use it for typewriting style.

```
<div class="rtypewriter mt-1" >  Text Letter be Letter  </div>

.rtypewriter{
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  animation: typing 8s steps(60, end)
}

@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}
```

May it helps someone