# Use jQuery to create slowly filling text

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show text letter by letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264974/show-text-letter-by-letter)

Bit hard to explain but what I'm trying to achieve is add text to a div BUT I don't want it to simply appear or fadeIn etc.  I want to be able to display the text a character at a time like if you were playing a text based game on the DS for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the Demo
http://www.thepixelart.com/demo/jticker/

Here is the downloadble file
http://www.thepixelart.com/demo/jticker/files/jticker.zip

You can modify the timer so that only one character would appear at particular time

(or)

html

```
<div id="text"><span>The intergalactic space agency</span></div>
```

css

> div#text { width: 0px; height: 2em; white-space: nowrap; overflow:
>   hidden;  }

jQuery

> var spanWidth = $('#test span').width(); $('#text').animate( { width:
>   spanWidth }, 1000 );

Here is the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/6qQrN/1/

Comment: For reference to others I also tried with the demo here: [link](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/) and simply changed the step to 0 to exclude the letter swapping which works as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to achieve a "typewriter" effect like you see in video games (using pure javascript, no jQuery required):

```
<div id="text"></div>​

<script type="text/javascript">
    var textToAdd = "your text here";
    var placeHolder = 0;

    var textAdder = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += textToAdd.charAt(placeHolder);
        if (++placeHolder == textToAdd.length){
            clearInterval(textAdder);
        }
    }, 100);
​</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/PRa8D/)