# Animate Text Slowly Inside List

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use jQuery to display text slowly, sorta like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962410/use-jquery-to-create-slowly-filling-text); thing is I'm mostly following the answer's jsfiddle and, while the animation is definitely working, the text just pops back up after the animation completes and it isn't entirely smooth - as long as the text isn't long enough, it'll animate, otherwise it does so for half of the animation, then suddenly jumps to display the text entirely

To see this last issue, remove the second animate function in the [fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962410/use-jquery-to-create-slowly-filling-text), so that the text never animates back to zero width.

I'm making a drawer type of menu, and it's slidable (but not completely - I can't just hide the entire drawer), so I just want the text to slide *with* the menu.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yoaquim/6qQrN/103/), and short example:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="drawer">
    <li class="drawer-item">
        <div class="item-name">
            <span>Feed</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
var itemNameWidth = $('.item-name span').width();
$('.item-name').animate({
   width: itemNameWidth
 }, 3000);
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, is there a better approach? I'd appreciate **any** type of suggestion, even if it isn't js related.

I'm also using angular; kinda new to it, so don't know if it could be of any help here.

Comment: Not that this answers your question, but you should really avoid effects like these—they're almost as bad as [`<marquee>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)s. They just aren't very visually pleasing and can be difficult for users to quickly and easily understand.

Comment: If you just want to hide the text after animation, then add overflow: hidden; to div#text http://jsfiddle.net/6qQrN/106/

Comment: @ Luxelin - In truth, the entire menu is what's gonna be hidden/partially hidden, the thing is the text is supposed to go along with it, not instantly appear/disappear; I've seen it in other, "pretty", well-built sites. I'm indifferent to the effect, but the client wants it, so...

Comment: @ Tushar - Thanks! Can't believe I overlooked that! The text still isn't displaying entirely though; could it be cause of the width I'm pre-defining? It being different for each different `<span>` maybe?

Comment: Hey rather than checking for width of ever span can't you use width: 100%, here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/6qQrN/112/

Comment: While it does extend to show the entire text, it also causes a line-break afterwards (not in the fiddle, tried it in the project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set id your span elements

like

```
<ul class="drawer">
<li class="drawer-item">
    <div class="item-name">
        <span id="id1" >Feed</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="drawer-item">
    <div class="item-name">
        <span id="id2" >Videos And More</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="drawer-item">
    <div class="item-name">
        <span id="id3" >Map and More Maps</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="drawer-item">
    <div class="item-name">
        <span id="id4" >Alerts</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

and then script like

```
var spanWidth = $('#text span').width();
var itemNameWidth=0;
for(i=1;i<=$('.item-name').length;i++)
{
if(itemNameWidth<$('#id'+i).width())
{
itemNameWidth = $('#id'+i).width();
 }
}

$('.item-name').animate({
width: itemNameWidth
}, 3000);

$('.item-name').animate({
width: "0"
}, 3000);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qQrN/110/)

Comment: Worked! Knew it had something to do with the different `<span>` widths! Thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: This may be better if you want the sliding to move all together. The id's are not needed. 
$('.item-name span').each(function(){ if($(this).width() > itemNameWidth) itemNameWidth = $(this).width();});

Answer (score 1):

in the .item-name css add:
`overflow:hidden;`

It looks like you are getting the width of the first span for all div's. I would loop through the spans for each width, and set the animation width for each div.

```
$('.item-name span').each(function(){
var itemNameWidth = $(this).width();
$(this).parent().animate({
    width: itemNameWidth
}, 3000);

$(this).parent().animate({
width: "0"
}, 3000);
```

});

Comment: Yeah, Tushar over in the comments pointed that out; the text still won't display entirely though.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6qQrN/105/) Check this,change duration time.

```
 $('.item-name').animate({width: itemNameWidth}, 5000);
```

Comment: The text still pops-up after the animation is complete.