# Letter-by-letter text appearance animation with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a `<div>` with text.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I'd like the text in this `<div>` to appear on page one character at a time:

```
L

Lo

Lor

... and so on, until the full text is visible
```

Acceptable alternative: do that one word at a time, to avoid problems with HTML entities and jumpy words due to soft hyphenation.

If user clicks on the `<div>`, it should cancel the animation and display the full text instantly.

In short, I want to imitate an animation that is frequently seen in Japanese-style adventure games. (I think that this is sometimes called a typewriter or teletype effect.)  Here is a good example:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=SasgN0lim7M#t=418

Obviously, I can script the animation using JavaScript — just set up a timer and append letters (or words) one-by-one.

But is it possible to do what I need with CSS in modern browsers? (Of course, I'd need to at least change element class in the `onclick` with JS, but that's OK.)

*Update:* To clarify on characters vs. letters and problems with HTML entities:

My text is littered with the HTML:

```
Lo&shy;rem <i>ip&shy;sum</i>.
```

Naïve approach with appending text to the `innerHTML` character-by-character wouldn't work:

```
L

Lo

Lo&

...Doh!
```

Comment: I think the best approach is to do what you have already suggested - JS with timer and append letters

Comment: Well, one thing is, browser knows better about what is a letter and what is not than the JS code I'd write.

Comment: Just do every character rather than a letter, I think that is a normal experience

Comment: No, a character-by-character animation is not possible with CSS. You only can animate the bounding rectangle of the text to grow, but that doesn't give a [typewriter effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074399/what-to-choose-for-typewriter-effect-in-javascript/13391131#13391131).

Comment: [Just for fun](http://jsfiddle.net/bzBzL/)

Comment: If you want it done via css then why you tagged javascript?

Comment: @shadow because the right technique would be a mix of CSS and JavaScript

Comment: @musefan Characters wouldn't do: my text is littered with `&shy;` and other markup stuff.

Comment: A [per word variation](http://jsfiddle.net/bzBzL/1/) should cater for that (it even handles simple inline tags, like `<b>`), though my code is starting to get quite hacky now, but demonstrates the concept

Comment: @musefan Thanks. Perhaps you should post that as an answer — along with a remark from Bergi about character-by-character animation and CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show text letter by letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264974/show-text-letter-by-letter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this with CSS so you will have to revert to a pure JS approach.

As your comments have explained, you require your text to contain some HTML markup so I would suggest a word-by-word animation being the easiest way to handle that. Something like this:

```
var timer, fullText, currentOffset, onComplete, wordSet;

function Speak(person, text, callback) {
    $("#name").html(person);
    fullText = text;
    wordSet = text.split(" ");
    currentOffset = 0;
    onComplete = callback;
    timer = setInterval(onTick, 300);
}

function onTick() {
    currentOffset++;
    if (currentOffset == wordSet.length) {
        complete();
        return;
    }
    var text = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < currentOffset; i++){
     text += wordSet[i] + " ";   
    }
    text.trim();
    $("#message").html(text);
}

function complete() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
    $("#message").html(fullText);
    if (onComplete) onComplete();
}

$(".box").click(function () {
    complete();
});

Speak("Simon",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",

function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        Speak("Javascript", "Simon has finished speaking!");
    }, 2000);
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bzBzL/1/)

**NOTE**: This code can likely be vastly re-factored to be more efficient and concise, but it should demonstrate the concept in full.

---

I also [created a letter-by-letter example](http://jsfiddle.net/bzBzL/). Although it doesn't support you html markup needs, it does look nicer so perhaps you can adapt it to work for you.

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this with a bit of jQuery.

**Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kA8G8/7/**

HTML

```
<p class="typewriter">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>
```

JS

```
var text = $('.typewriter').text();

var length = text.length;
var timeOut;
var character = 0;


(function typeWriter() { 
    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        character++;
        var type = text.substring(0, character);
        $('.typewriter').text(type);
        typeWriter();

        if (character == length) {
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

    }, 150);
}());
```

Comment: Wouldn't work for text with HTML entities. I've update the question to further clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pure CSS trick to do this.

Use a mask element, even a pseudo element `p:before` or `p:after` with a higher z-index than your text element. Give it the same color as the text background and the height of a line. Place it with absolute position just above the text.

Then you just have to animate it to make it move to the right, unmasking letter by letter.
It's just a workaround, because if you have a complex background under the text, like an image, then this trick is difficult to reproduce because you will have to map the background image on the masking element.

Comment: Useful trick, but would only work if you could guarantee that the text being on one line.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not related, but I like this kind of animations so I created this tool:
https://imageecho.app/

enjoy!

Comment: how does this answer the question? this creates a gif- not actual text animation with CSS