# Print text out slowly, and interpret html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found the following function on [Show text letter by letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264974/show-text-letter-by-letter)

**Javascript:**

```
      <script type='text/javascript'>
           var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {
           if (index < message.length) {
                $(target).append(message[index++]);
                     setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
                }
           }
      </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class='console' id='white' color='white'></span>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
      showText('#white', 'Text<br>blah<br>', 0, 50);
 });
 </script>
```

is more or less how it works. I want to do the same, but allow multiple lines. It doesn't render the `<br>` tags though, instead it writes them out.

### 1. Why is it handled like this?

### 2. How can I get the expected results?

**Note:** I'm not experienced with Javascript at all, and apologize for the probability that this is an easy question.

**--EDIT--**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls6mW/

Comment: (1) The reason it is doing that is because anything between the singlequotes is being taken literally, not being translated by an html parser. (2) My first guess was to try using `\n` or `\r`, the literal newline or carriage return characters in javascript, but those didn't work for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Each character is being taken as it's literal value because it is being stored in a string and taken letter by letter.
2. I'm not sure why `\n` and `\r` are not working, so I wrote a little work around that will allow `\n` to work.

Basically, check each character that is passed through the string when you print it. If it is a newline character, insert a break:

```
if(message[index]=='\n'){
  $(target).append("<br />");
}
```

And then add `\n` wherever you want a newline in your text:

```
showText("#msg", "H\ne\nl\nl\no\n,\n \nW\no\nr\nl\nd\n!", 0, 50);
```

This is just a quick-fix, work-around-type-thing. I'd love to know if there is an actual reason line breaks don't work with this.

Here is a working version:
http://jsfiddle.net/VZvK7/192/

Comment: It's strange that it doesn't work. Prehaps it's meant to be that way? As you said "Each character is being taken as it's literal value", `\n` could be taken as just `\ ` and then `n`. All aside, works fine!

Comment: If that were the case, the work-around I wrote wouldn't function. In Javascript `\n` is literally one character. However, the strange thing we ran into, it isn't being interpreted correctly. (Or perhaps, as you say, it's meant to be that way...) I tried using `\r` instead and it added an extra space instead of a "carriage return" only adding to my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** The `<br>` tag is literally being interpreted as a string, not html content, because of the way your function accesses each character of the string by index. Likewise, this is what happens if you use `/n`.

**2.** You need to catch a special case, either by a single character or through some other means. Here is an example for catching a single special character, in this case an ampersand (`&`) and interpreting it as a new line character:

```
 $(function () {
      showText('#white', 'Text&blah&thirdline&fourthline', 0, 50);
 });

function showText (target, message, index, interval) {
    if (index < message.length) {
        var next = message[index++];
        if (next == '&') {
            $(target).append('<br>');  
        } else {
            $(target).append(next);
        }
        setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
    }
}
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EF72k/).

You may want to consider catching an entire string (i.e. the entire `<br>`) but this is just an example of a possible solution.

Comment: That makes sense, however, `\n` doesn't change anything. It's still on the same line, I forgot to mention I had already tried that.

Comment: Have you considered uploading a jsfiddle?