# Fade in letter by letter with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the text of the all_msg, and with the hide method to hide it and then fade it in one letter at a time, with a tiny delay, this is my code.

```
var $all_msg = $('#welcome_msg');
        function animate(i) {
            $all_msg.hide();
            $all_msg.text.each(function(index) {
                $(this).delay(700 + index).fadeIn(1100);
            })
        }
```

and this is what the console is giving me back:

```
$all_msg.text.each is not a function
```

I'm a new coder if someone can help me it will give me a major boost, thanks.

Comment: 'one text at a time' - What exactly is a *text* in this context? A character?

Comment: One letter at a time, thanks I fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to retrieve the text with `.text()`, then split it with a delimiter of your choice (space to get a list of words, or empty string to get a list of characters), then create a span for each of the items in the list and append it to a container on your page(and fade them if you want):

```js
$(function() {
  //get the welcome msg element
  var $all_msg = $('#welcome_msg');
  //get a list of letters from the welcome text
  var $wordList = $('#welcome_msg').text().split("");
  //clear the welcome text msg
  $('#welcome_msg').text("");
  //loop through the letters in the $wordList array
  $.each($wordList, function(idx, elem) {
    //create a span for the letter and set opacity to 0
    var newEL = $("<span/>").text(elem).css({
      opacity: 0
    });
    //append it to the welcome message
    newEL.appendTo($all_msg);
    //set the delay on the animation for this element
    newEL.delay(idx * 70);
    //animate the opacity back to full 1
    newEL.animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 1100);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="welcome_msg">Welcome to the example snippet</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

here is a snippet that minds markup inside the welcome text:

```js
$(function() {
  //get the welcome msg element
  var $all_msg = $('#welcome_msg');
  //get a list of letters from the welcome text
  var $wordList = $('#welcome_msg').html().split("");
  //clear the welcome text msg
  $('#welcome_msg').html("");
  //loop through the letters in the $wordList array
  var tagGoing = "";
  $.each($wordList, function(idx, elem) {

    if (elem == "<") {
      //if we encountered this symbol it means a tag started
      tagGoing += elem;
    } else if (elem == ">") {
      //if we encountered this symbol it means a tag closed
      tagGoing += elem;
      //create the tag from the collected parts and append it
      //to the output html:
      var $foundTag = $(tagGoing).appendTo($all_msg);
      $foundTag.css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $foundTag.delay(idx * 70);
      $foundTag.animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 1100);

      //reset the tag collector:
      tagGoing = "";
    } else {
      //if we are inside a tag
      if (tagGoing != "") {
        //if we are inside a tag, then just append the
        //current character to the output html
        tagGoing += elem;
      } else {

        //create a span for the letter and set opacity to 0
        var newEL = $("<span/>").text(elem).css({
          opacity: 0
        });
        //append it to the welcome message
        newEL.appendTo($all_msg);
        //set the delay on the animation for this element
        newEL.delay(idx * 70);
        //animate the opacity back to full 1
        newEL.animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, 1100);
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.banana {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="welcome_msg">Welcome to the
  <br/>example
  <div class="banana"></div>snippet</div>
```

Comment: and what is if I have markup in the msg that I want to animate, it all gets striped out, how can I preserve it?

Comment: I tried to swap in .html() instead of .text() what I got is displayed all markup!

Comment: @DavidGenger if you use `.html()` then it will wrap every single character in the markup with a span and display them as text instead :) you need a more clever approach than what i presented in the answer, i need to think about it for a while :)

Comment: @DavidGenger basically one way to do it would be to take all the `.html()`, and during the iteration over the characters, keep an eye for a `<`, if found one than anything after it belongs to an html tag, and just append it to the container until you encounter a closing one `>`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it, once I find a < I should append it to what?

Comment: @DavidGenger well, we are iterating over the html character by character. if we encounter a `<` it means that we have found a tag, so everything after the `<` until a closing `>` is inside a tag and needs to be appended as is to the html of the welcome message

Comment: @DavidGenger i have updated the answer with an example that minds the markup. i hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrap each character in a new element, probably a `<span />` in this instance. Let's first create a simple jQuery method that does that - better code reuse this way.

This method replaces each character inside the element with a new element, wrapping the character up. You can pass in whatever options you need to use. Below we set the opacity, and a class to identify our characters with.

```
$.fn.characterize = function (wrapper, options) {
  var txt = this.text(),
      self = this;

  this.empty();


  options = options || {};

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(txt, function (c) {
    options.text = c;
    self.append($(wrapper, options));
  });
};
```

Now let's use this to break our word apart, and animate each new element separately.

```
function animate () {
  var wlc = $('#welcome');

  wlc.characterize('<span />', {
    class: 'fd',
    css: {
      opacity: 0
    }
  });

  wlc.css('opacity', 1);

  $('.fd').each(function (i) {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, (i + 1) * 300);
  });
}
```

You'll also want to hide the element before hand with CSS, and show it again before animating to avoid any flickering while building the elements, or while jQuery is loaded.

All together now.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/powuva/edit?html,css,js,output)</kbd>

```js
$.fn.characterize = function (wrapper, options) {
  var txt = this.text(),
      self = this;

  this.empty();

  wrapper = wrapper || '<span />';
  options = options || {};

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(txt, function (c) {
    options.text = c;
    self.append($(wrapper, options));
  });
};


function animate () {
  var wlc = $('#welcome');

  wlc.characterize('<span />', {
    class: 'fd',
    css: {
      opacity: 0
    }
  });
  
  wlc.css('opacity', 1);

  $('.fd').each(function (i) {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, (i + 1) * 300);
  });
}


animate();
```

```css
#welcome {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="welcome">Welcome</h1>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```