# each-event with scroll in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I would like to have an simple animation for text, but the animation should start when the user is scrolled to the element.

I found this [Fade in letter by letter with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832400/fade-in-letter-by-letter-with-jquery) and modified like this:

```
(function($) {

//get the welcome msg element
var $all_msg = $('#welcome_msg');
//get a list of letters from the welcome text
var $wordList = $('#welcome_msg').text().split("");
//clear the welcome text msg
$('#welcome_msg').text("");
//loop through the letters in the $wordList array
$.each($wordList, function(idx, elem) {
    //create a span for the letter and set opacity to 0
    var newEL = $("<span/>").text(elem).css({
        opacity: 0
    });
    //append it to the welcome message
    newEL.appendTo($all_msg);
    //set the delay on the animation for this element
    newEL.delay(idx * 20);
    // Var for scrolling
    var hT = $('#welcome_msg').offset().top,
        hH = $('#welcome_msg').outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
            //animate the opacity back to full 1
            newEL.animate({
              opacity: 1
             }, 1100);
       }
    });
    
});
})( jQuery );
```

Sadly it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make a snippet adding the relevant html

Comment: "[\[I\]t's not working](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/133817)" doesn't sufficiently describe the issue. State exactly what you want and what you get, so it's clear what the difference is. Also, [code samples](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative. To exand on Lelio's comment, you can read more about [snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/90527) on meta.SO.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get scroll top inside the window scroll handler not outside of it

```js
(function($) {

//get the welcome msg element
var $all_msg = $('#welcome_msg');
//get a list of letters from the welcome text
var $wordList = $('#welcome_msg').text().split("");
//clear the welcome text msg
$('#welcome_msg').text("");
//loop through the letters in the $wordList array
$.each($wordList, function(idx, elem) {
    //create a span for the letter and set opacity to 0
    var newEL = $("<span/>").text(elem).css({
        opacity: 0
    });
    //append it to the welcome message
    newEL.appendTo($all_msg);
    //set the delay on the animation for this element
    newEL.delay(idx * 20);
    // Var for scrolling
    var hT = $('#welcome_msg').offset().top,
        hH = $('#welcome_msg').outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height();

        //console.log(hT,hH, wH);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      wS = $(this).scrollTop(); 
      //console.log(wS, hT+hH-wH);
       if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
            //animate the opacity back to full 1
            newEL.animate({
             opacity: 1
            }, 1100);
       }
    });
    
});
})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:800px">section with height to scroll</div>
<div id="welcome_msg">Welcome to the example snippet</div>
```