# $welcome.css is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a jQuery method to a variable that holds a string, but it does not work.  the purpose of it is to fade in letter by letter, I know that I can do it threw selecting the node so it is an object, but I try to do it from a variable. If someone can help me find the issue please.
This is the code:

```
function y() {
    var $welcome = allName.split("");
    $welcome.css({opacity: 0});
    $welcome.each().css({
    });
```

This is what I get back:

> $welcome.css is not a function

There is a string stored in `allname`.

Comment: Maybe `$($welcome).css('opacity', 0)`?

Comment: Well, `.split` returns an array. Arrays don't have these methods.

Comment: `$welcome` is an array, not a jquery object. Thus, `.css` doesn't exist. It's not a function for an array object.

If you create `$welcome` as a DOM element, you can use `.css`.

That said, we're gonna need more code to give you an actual solution to your problem.

Comment: What type is `allName`? Also, what are you actually trying to accomplish in this method, so we know how to fix it?

Comment: What's the value of `allName`? What is the exact value of `$welcome`? Why do you want to use the value as jQuery object? More information is required.

Comment: @Katana314: The value of `allName` is a string.

Comment: splitting the string then applying css to $welcome and then each statement doesnt make any sense..I guess you should split it...use each then apply css to the splitted part

Comment: Im trying to fade in letter by letter, so im storing the string and i wana add jquery (this is not the full code) and it dose not seem to work, as if jquery dose not work on strings stored in var's,

Comment: Yes, jQuery works on DOM elements, not text. If you want to fade in text letter by letter, you  could put each letter inside an element, add the elements to the document and manipulate those.

Comment: If you used the search, you would have found [Show text letter by letter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7264974/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split function will return an array. Since you are trying to call '.css' on on array you are getting an error