# How to make text display slower?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make any text (for example a `h1` tag) `display` slower on my web page almost like the `CSS3` tag `-webkit-transition-duration` / `transition-duration` gives of an effect?

I don't have any code to  provide as I'm just curious, also, I didn't find anything useful on the internet (can't promise that I've searched in every page) or "related" question.

Does it require `JavaScript`? (If I wasn't clear enough, I can provide an example).

Comment: So, you want it to fade in after the page has loaded?

Comment: Yep, like a fade-in. @JacobGray

Comment: Nope, JS not needed, css animation on opacity for example would do that and take as long or short a time as you want

Comment: a 3 seconds fade in http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/L6apwnte/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you want to do. If you just want to `fade-in` the text all at once (or some other *animation*), `css3` is probably sufficient to handle this.

If you're trying to display the text letter-by-letter (as you'd find in an RPG, for example), then you'll need code to iterate over the string and write it one letter at a time.

Here's an example of this in `javascript`, taken directly from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265613/3456453) answer to a similar question:

```
var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {   
  if (index < message.length) {
    $(target).append(message[index++]);
    setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
  }
}
```

Essentially, the code looks at each index of the data passed into it (`t`, then `h`, then `e`) for instance, and writes it to your target one letter at a time.

Please see the linked answer for additional details.

Here is a good link on [CSS3 Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).
Additionally, [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) has some great functions for a number of animations that go beyond what `CSS` can do on its own, if you don't mind using a plugin.

As an aside, you should keep in mind browser compatibility when you're trying to perform animations like this. Older browsers likely will have spotty or *no* support for this kind of thing, so you should have a fall-back.

EDIT:

Sorry to add another link, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29170639/3456453) is a good implementation on displaying one word at a time. This code is taken directly from the linked answer, with my explanation added:

```
var textToDisplay = "Even more awesome text inside here, but displayed one word at a time",
  $output = $("p");

$("button").click(function() {
  var displayInt;
  textToDisplay = textToDisplay.split(' '); //split the text variable into an array
  $output.empty(); //clear out the $output variable
  displayInt = setInterval(function() {
    var word = textToDisplay.shift(); //removes the first word ("Even") and sets the word variable to that value
    if (word == null) { return clearInterval(displayInt); } //if we're out of words to append
    $output.append(word + ' '); //else, add the word and then a space (.split(' ') will not carry over the spaces)
  }, 300); //setInterval is delayed 300ms, so a word will be added every 300ms
});
```

Note this method *and* the one I added previously both use `jQuery` (the `$` symbol is a `jQuery` prefix). If you click the link to the second answer, there is a snip that lets you try out this code.

Comment: Oh, okay thanks for providing the `JavaScript`, really appreciate it!

Comment: What do you think suits best if I want to `fade-in` one word at the time? `JavaScript` or `CSS3`?

Comment: @JamesSnowy I would think that JavaScript is "easiest" here, unless you happen to have separate tags for each word as was mentioned in the comments. I'm trying to write a simple implementation of doing it one word at a time, but I'm not terribly great with JavaScript. I'll edit the post shortly, but take it with a grain of salt :)

Comment: Thanks man for everything, I will look forward to the demo! :)

Comment: @JamesSnowy Please see my edit - I've added another link to an existing answer that shows text word-by-word, and added some explanation of what the code is doing.

Comment: How can I make the words display like a `fade-in` with the JavaScript code?

Comment: Can you write it in vanilla?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with CSS3 animations:

```css
h1{
  animation:fadeIn 5s;
  }
@keyframes fadeIn{
  0%{opacity:0;}  
  80%{opacity:0;}
  100%{opacity:1;}
  }
```

```html
<h1>I fade In</h1>
```

This snippet will wait for 4 seconds, then fade in the h1.

Code explanation:

```
h1{
  /*Since we want the h1 to fade in, and stay there, we cannot use animation-delay.*/
  animation:fadeIn 5s;
  /*Instead, we can add the delay by setting the animation to longer*/
  }
@keyframes fadeIn{/*Then, don't actually animate anything for, in this case, 4 seconds*/
  0%{opacity:0;}  
  80%{opacity:0;}
  100%{opacity:1;}
  }
```

If you want to fade in one letter at a time, you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Is there any way to display one letter / word at the time?

Comment: @JamesSnowy that would require really messy HTML, it is easier just to use JS for that

Comment: @JamesSnowy - You would have to wrap each letter in a `<span>` or else just use JS

Comment: Hm, interesting, would you like to go to a chat to talk further more about this?

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript in combination with CSS3 animation you can achieve this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/hgbt9uod/) where you wrap each letter with a `span` and add CSS animation to it with delay value depending on that letter's position thus you can for exampel fade-in text letter by letter:

```js
var $test = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML, $html = '', $i;

for ($i = 0; $i < $test.length; $i++) {
  $html += '<span style="animation: foo ' + $i + 's">' + ($test[$i]) + '</span>';
}
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = $html;
```

```css
@keyframes foo {
  0%, 10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="test">I am Sample Text</h1>
```

---

And thus you can animate different properties not only fade-in, for example to change the color smoothly letter by letter [**JS Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/hgbt9uod/1/)

```js
var $test = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML, $html = '', $i;

for($i=0; $i<$test.length; $i++){
 $html += '<span style="animation: foo ' +$i+'s">' + ($test[$i]) + '</span>';
}
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = $html;
document.getElementById('test').style.color = 'green';
```

```css
@keyframes foo{
  0%,10%{color:orange;}
  15%,100%{color:green;}
}
```

```html
<h1 id="test">I am Sample Text</h1>
```