# Show multiple texts letter by letter after another (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, animation, bots, letter

I want to make a simple chat bot. It should be able to write multiple lines after another. My problem is that I can't figure out on how to make them NOT appear at the same time, but after another (maybe with a delay in between to make it more realistic).

Related question:
[Show text letter by letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264974/show-text-letter-by-letter)

Attempted code:
http://jsfiddle.net/VZvK7/1447/

```
<div id="msg"/> 
<span id="text_target"></span></div>
<div id="msg2"/> 
<span id="text_target"></span></div>
<div id="msg3"/> 
<span id="text_target"></span></div>

var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {    
if (index < message.length) { 
    $(target).append(message[index++]); 
    setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); },   interval); 
  } 
}

$(function () { 

showText("#msg", "Hello, World!", 0, 500);    
showText("#msg2", "Hello, World!", 0, 500);
showText("#msg3", "Hello, World!", 0, 500);
});
```

Comment: Do you want to switch up the time of the interval?

Comment: @Sylent I only want to make strings (in this case all 3 "Hello World!") appear after another, possible with a delay in between

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const printMessage = (target, message, frequency) => {
    message.forEach((line, lineIndex) => {
    const baseInterval = message.slice(0, lineIndex).join(' ').length * frequency
    line.split('').forEach((character, charIndex) => {
        const t = setTimeout(() => {
        target.innerHTML = `${target.innerHTML}${character}${charIndex === line.length - 1 ? '<br/>' : ''}`
        clearTimeout(t)
      }, baseInterval + charIndex * frequency)
    })
  })
}

const target = document.getElementById('target')

printMessage(target, [
    'Hello World!',
    'How are you ?'
], 100)
```

JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/VZvK7/1452/

Comment: Looks great! is it possible to put each message in its own div? Also, is it possible to add a delay between each message? Thanks a lot!