# How to print multi-line text letter by letter from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, output, runtime-error

I want to print my text letter by letter using JavaScript. I tried the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265613/7920589 which is in jQuery by converting it into plain javascript.

```
     let showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {
            if (index < message.length) {
                document.querySelector(target).innerText += message[index++];

                setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
            }
            }
     showText("#msg", "Hello this line is printing letter by letter\n hello this line too is printing letter by letter,", 0, 200);
```

I tried this code but though it prints the message letter by letter, it completely ignores the spaces in the message.

**OUTPUT:**

```
Hellothislineisprintingletterbyletter
hellothislinetooisprintingletterbyletter,
```

I tried replacing `innerText` with `innerHTML` and `textContent` but then the new line escape character `\n` does not work and instead prints a simple space instead on going to a new line.

**OUTPUT:**

```
Hello this line is printing letter by letter hello this line too is printing letter by letter,
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `<code>` tag in combination with `textContent` and `white-space: pre-wrap`:

```js
let showText = function(target, message, index, interval) {
  if (index < message.length) {
    document.querySelector(target).textContent += message[index++];

    setTimeout(function() {
      showText(target, message, index, interval);
    }, interval);
  }
}
showText("#msg", "Hello this line is printing letter by letter\n hello this line too is printing letter by letter,", 0, 20);
```

```css
code {
  white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

```html
<code id="msg"></code>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to what CertainPerformance proposed is to slice the text.

```js
let showText = function(target, message, index, interval) {
  if (index < message.length) {
    document.querySelector(target).textContent = message.slice(0, index);

    setTimeout(function() {
      showText(target, message, index + 1, interval);
    }, interval);
  }
}
showText("#msg", "Hello this line is printing letter by letter\n hello this line too is printing letter by letter,", 0, 20);
```

```css
div {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this kind of loop to print letter by letter

```
<input type="text" id="input1">
<button onclick="his()">click</button>
```

and the js

```
function his() {
    let input = document.getElementById("input1").value
    for (let index of input) {
        console.log(index)
    }
}
```

i just discover this type of loop and its kinda has short syntax. maybe this could help